The movie/show in a prison where the bad guy tests all the inmates blood?
I think it's an open prison where the inmates control themselves. The inmate leader tests every new inmate's blood to see if he can find a compatible match to cure him. There is a young kid who is a match and the hero saves from being killed. I'm watching Prison Break season 3 and am seeing similarities, though I think the above story is from something else.

Any idea when you saw it/when it was released?

No sorry..can't really remember anything more than what I posted.

Google has turned up a possibility...
Does Get the Gringo (2012) starring Mel Gibson sound familiar? 
Bolded parts match your description:  
From a IMDb.com review:

.... Basically after being caught during a robbery of
  millions of dollars from his boss, an unnamed American criminal known
  simply as the Driver (Mel Gibson, also writing and producing) is not
  sent to prison back in the United States, but instead being caught by
  the Mexican authorities he is taken to a Mexican prison. This prison,
  called El Pueblito is different from the regular kind however, it is
  an open space that looks like a village, and in it live the various
  prisoners that have been arrested, from petty criminals to hardcore
  drug dealers and killers, and most of them live with their families
  inside. As the Driver gets to know his way around the town like prison
  he meets a ten year old Kid (Kevin Hernandez) who knows much more
  about his surroundings than the American, and as long as he gets
  cigarettes to stop his craving and some other favours he helps the
  American learn the ropes to get around the prison. He also explains a
  key factor, that the Mexican boss (or rather the head criminal) of the
  prison is in need of a liver so he will not die, but he has a very
  rare blood type, which explains why all criminals entering the prison
  had their blood taken, so they will know whether there is a match, and
  it seems the only matching blood type belongs to the Kid. So it is up
  to the Driver, also nicknamed by the Mexicans as the Gringo, to stop
  the criminals from taking the Kid's liver, and of course escape the
  prison with all the money that he stole, and he has various methods to
  help him do this.... 

.
.
Wikipedia summary:

The film opens with a getaway driver (Mel Gibson) and a wounded
  accomplice dressed as clowns fleeing from American police toward the
  Mexican border. The driver crashes through the border fence, whereupon
  he is arrested by corrupt Mexican police officers Vasquez (Mario
  Zaragoza) and Romero (Gerardo Teracena). When they find over $2
  million in the car, they incarcerate him in El Pueblito prison under
  false charges, keep the cash for themselves, and cremate the
  accomplice, who by then has died. As one of the only Americans
  incarcerated there, the driver becomes known as "the Gringo". El
  Pueblito proves surprising, operating more like a small ghetto than a
  prison. The Gringo quickly manages to work out the prison's criminal
  hierarchy and engages in petty thefts and robberies from some of the
  prison's less reputable businesses. One of these thefts is witnessed
  by an unnamed kid (Kevin Hernandez) who is living with his
  incarcerated mother (Dolores Heredia) and is protected by the prison's
  criminals. Curious, the Gringo presses him to explain why the
  criminals protect him, but the Kid refuses.
Later, the Gringo stops the Kid from an ill-fated assassination
  attempt on Javi (Daniel Giménez Cacho), leader of the crime family
  that runs El Pueblito. After an argument, he learns why the Kid is
  protected: Javi has a failing liver, and the Kid is the only viable
  match; Javi has already killed and harvested the liver from the Kid's
  father. The Gringo vows to stop the transplant from happening and to
  help kill Javi. Meanwhile, the Gringo attracts the attention of an
  American Embassy employee (Peter Gerety), who easily identifies him as
  a career criminal. Unconcerned, the Gringo and the Kid work towards
  bringing down Javi, and the Gringo grows closer to the Kid's mother.
  The Gringo ingratiates himself to Javi by saving Javi's brother,
  Caracas (Jesús Ochoa) and revealing the money stolen by Vasquez and
  Romero. Thugs working for criminal boss Frank (Peter Stormare) have
  already located Vasquez and Romero and are torturing them to find the
  location of an additional $2 million. Javi's men kill everyone and
  take the money, enraging Frank. With the aid of the Embassy guy, Frank
  sends assassins into El Pueblito to kill Javi and the Gringo.
The resulting shootout results in the Mexican authorities planning a
  raid on the prison. Knowing time is short, Javi hires the Gringo to
  kill Frank and sets up an immediate transplant operation. In the US,
  the Gringo lures Frank out of hiding by arranging a meeting between
  him and shipping magnate Warren Kaufmann (Bob Gunton). The Gringo sets
  up his ex-partner, who betrayed him, and kills Frank. When the Gringo
  ambushes the Embassy guy, he learns of the transplant operation and
  rushes to save the Kid, who has unsuccessfully attempted to stab
  himself in the liver. Using the Embassy guy's credentials, the Gringo
  infiltrates the raid on the prison and interrupts Javi's operation.
  Threatening to kill Javi, the Gringo forces Caracas to retrieve the
  kid's mother, who Javi has tortured. Caracas returns with several
  thugs, but the Gringo kills them all. A nurse helps the Gringo by
  pretending to capture him. When Caracas relaxes, the nurse shoots him.
  They grab the money, and the nurse helps them escape from the prison
  in an ambulance. In the epilogue, the Gringo recovers the missing $2
  million hidden in the escape car, and the Gringo, the Kid, and his
  mother retire to an idyllic beach, while Kauffman kills the Gringo's
  ex-partner.


Yeah Mel Gibson for sure..thanks. Surprising how similar it is to Prison Break season 3 in a lot of ways.
